# Executor/Launchy alternative for linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, gnome-do

I am a new ubuntu user and I am looking for an alternative of Executor http://executor.dk/ , a keystroke launcher. I mentioned Launchy as most people know it. I have tried Gnome DO which is very similar to Launchy and it's good but there I still miss Executor.

The major difference between Launchy and Executor is the the emphasis on user defined keywords, which allow users to set keywords for launching any given application.In other words you can create your own commands/keystrokes.

I also don't like Gnome DO indexing all my programs,as I don't use all of them,instead I like to make my keywords/progs/folders paths.

Comment: Launchy is available for linux.  Not sure if you are aware of that or if that is why you mentioned it.  Also Gnome-Do is quite configureable as it has the alias plugin where you can in fact define your own commands.  As far as it indexing your programs....I guess you would just have to disable almost all of the programs.  Good luck in your hunt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [**Kupfer**](http://kaizer.se/wiki/kupfer/)

What you can do with Kupfer?

- Grab current selection
- Add applications
- Add your scripts
- Add your commandlines
- Command-line connection
- Managing Context and Current Selection
- The "Comma Trick"
- Save Commands as Files ([GIF screencast illustration](http://kaizer.se/publicfiles/kupfer-stuff/Kupfer-Save-Command-as-File.gif))

[Kupfer Manual](http://kaizer.se/wiki/kupfer/help/)

Answer (score 7):

Why no love for [Synapse](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/synapse-gnome-do-launcher-app-review-ubuntu/)?

Just like GNOME Do and similar launchers Synapse is ‘called’ using the keyboard combination Ctrl + Space. If you have a different shortcut hardwired into your actual synapses you can change it to any combination you like via the settings menu.

**Features**:

The default set of plugins shipped with Synapse are as follows: -

- Applications – searches your desktop files Banshee – allows you to
  play/enqueue music files in Banshee Commands – runs any command (ie.
  “sudo apt-get update”) Devhelp – search documentation using Devhelp
  Dictionary – find definitions of words Directory search – allows
  opening of commonly used directories Gnome session – log out, shut
  down, restart Hybrid search – complete Zeitgeist results by searching
  for similar files Rhytmbox – play/enqueue music files in Rhythmbox
  UPower – suspend & hibernate your computer Zeitgeist – search
  anything logged by Zeitgeist But thanks to the Zeitgeist integration
  pretty much any application can integrate with Synapse simply by
  integrating with Zeitgeist.

[image]

**Install:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install synapse
```

Comment: Note Synapse tries to learn which commands and files are used often (nepomuk integration)

Comment: +1 Synapse *just works*! 

Was moving from Windows to xubuntu, so I tried to use Launchy but 1. had to manually configure to launch on startup, didn't have a dialog to setup from the app 2. didn't work with apps opened with .sh files (opens the file in text editor) 3. didn't detect apps like Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use AutoHotKey a lot in Windows to automate things a bit.

The Linux equivalent is [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/) the main difference between the projects
is Autokey uses Python for scripting instead of its own language.

Here is a list of Features from the project home page

- KDE and GTK versions available, making AutoKey integrate well into
  any desktop environment.
- Write Python scripts to automate virtually any task that can be
  accomplished via the keyboard
- Built-in code editor (using QScintilla in KDE or GtkSourceView2 in
  GTK)
- Create phrases (blocks of text) to be pasted into any program on
  demand (uses the X selection)
- Create collections of phrases/scripts in folders, and assign a hotkey
  or abbreviation to the folder to display a popup menu
- Regular expressions can be used to filter windows by their title, to
  exclude hotkeys/abbreviations from triggering in certain applications
- Scripts, phrases and folders can be attached to the tray icon menu,
  allowing you to select them without assigning a hotkey or
  abbreviation
- AutoKey can track your usage patterns and present the most frequently
  used items at the top of the popup menu

Hope this is What you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can write shell scripts as user defined keywords for Gnome Do.

Also, I really like KDE's Krunner dialogue. Of course, it won't work in Gnome.